# How not to clean disabled inputs in the form jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How not to clean disabled inputs in the form. I need to clear only enabled inputs. I use this code:

```
$('form[id="addFromReport"] button:reset').click(function () {
    $('form[id="addFromReport"]')
        .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
        .find('textarea, :text, select').val('');

    return false;
});
```

It clears all the fields (enabled and disabled). I have added `.find ('input:enabled:not([disabled])')` and `.find('input:enabled')`. After this cleaning does not work.

Comment: how about using `.find ( 'input:enabled').not(":disabled")` instead...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:input` selector to get all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements in your `form`, and then the `:enabled` selector. Also note that it's better practice to use `prop()` and set `checked` to `false` instead of removing the attribute, and you should use the id selector instead of the attribute selector to get the `form`.

Try this:

```
$('#addFromReport button:reset').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addFromReport')
        .find(':radio, :checkbox').prop('checked', false).end()
        .find(':input:enabled').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('form[id="addFromReport"] button:reset').click(function () {
                $('form[id="addFromReport"]')
                    .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
                    .find(':input:enabled').val('');

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: Note that this only retrieves `input` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form[id="addFromReport"] button:reset').click(function () {
    $('form[id="addFromReport"]').filter(':enabled')
        .find(':radio, :checkbox').removeAttr('checked').end()
        .find('textarea, :text, select').val('');

    return false;
});
```

Why not filter the `:enabled` items and then find what you are looking for. Hope it helps